# Google Cloud Talent Solution returning Error 7 PERMISSION_DENIED The caller does not have permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-talent-solution

I can't use the Google Cloud Talent Solution, whatever I try I always end up getting "Error 7 PERMISSION DENIED: The caller does not have permission"

Hello everyone, I already did the [Before You Begin](https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/docs/before-you-begin#overview) three times in two different accounts and I always end up bumping into the exception "Error 7 PERMISSION DENIED: The caller does not have permission" when I try to use Google Cloud Talent Solution.

Initially I was trying to use the PHP package, but then I went to use the Node.js thinking it could help but still getting same error.

The code I'm using is straight from their [create tenant example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/main/talent/snippet/job_search_create_tenant.js)

[image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, should I be using something more specific as `project_id` or `external_id` for it to work? I already tried using the `project_id` inside the OAuth2 JSON file generated during the [Before You Begin](https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/docs/before-you-begin#overview) but still get the same error.

I'm already exporting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, it's probably something silly but I can't figure out what

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing an appropriate permission prior to the tenant creation. You can use the "Editor" role for your service account as described in the [CTS predefined roles](https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/docs/iam#roles).

> roles/editor - Read-write access to all GCP and CTS resources except the ability to modify permissions and billing.

Adding these resources to help you learn more about other authentication or permission methods that you can use

- [Choosing the right authentication method for your use case](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#auth-decision-tree)
- [Setting up an Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc)
- [Understanding how ADC works](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials)